# SASLError using PLAIN: not-authorized

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am trying to shift my app from `aSmack` to `Smack 4.1.1`. However I am having trouble using the same server and login details in the case of Smack while on aSmack it is working excellently.

Here's my old code of login in `aSmack` -

```
void startConnect(boolean sslFlag) throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException {
        ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, Integer.parseInt(PORT), SERVICE);
        connectionConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        connectionConfig.setCompressionEnabled(false);

        if (sslFlag)
            SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connectionConfig);

            connection.connect();
            connection.login(mUserName, mUserPassword, getResource());

            // Set status to online / available
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            setConnection(connection);
    }
```

I am trying to use code on similar fashion in `Smack` too -

```
public void init() {
        SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true;
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setHost(SERVICE_NAME)
                .setPort(5222)
                .setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .build();
        mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

//I have tried with blacklisting and unblacklisting all three mechanism.
        //SASLMechanism mechanism = new SASLPlainMechanism(); //This didn't help
        //SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism(mechanism);
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("SCRAM-SHA-1");
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
        SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN"); 
        try {
            mConnection.connect();
            return;
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mConnection = null;
    }

    public void login(String username, String password) throws IOException, XMPPException, SmackException {

        if(mConnection==null || !mConnection.isConnected()){
            init();
            if(mConnection==null){
                throw new IOException();
            }
        }
        mConnection.login(username/*+"@"+SERVICE_NAME*/, password); //I have tried both the method by adding @Domain part and without it.

        mChatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
        mChatManager.addChatListener(this);
    }
```

Here's the exception I am getting -

```
05-21 21:22:29.782  19536-23179/test W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using PLAIN: not-authorized
05-21 21:22:29.782  19536-23179/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticationFailed(SASLAuthentication.java:365)
05-21 21:22:29.792  19536-23179/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1033)
05-21 21:22:29.792  19536-23179/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
05-21 21:22:29.792  19536-23179/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
05-21 21:22:29.792  19536-23179/test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This exception is same with SCRAM and DIGEST-MD5 too. It just changes the name.

Here's what I am getting from server -

```
05-21 21:22:29.512  19536-23189/test D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='xmpp.example.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
05-21 21:22:29.642  19536-23190/test D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='214326363' from='xmpp.example.com' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'><stream:features><compression xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/compress'><method>zlib</method></compression><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='hX7OB6oTZugjNIFHZvd95k5UYzc='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
05-21 21:22:29.652  19536-23189/test D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>ADEwMDAAMTAwMA==</auth>
05-21 21:22:29.782  19536-23190/test D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/></failure>
```

What could be the issue here? I have tried with all three mechanism `PLAIN`, `DIGEST-MD5` and the default `SCRAM-SHA-1`. I have also tried with or without adding domain name on it. I have tried it with adding username and password in configuration and by adding it directly on login method.

I have tried with required security mode too which gives the following error -

```
05-21 21:27:53.658  25643-26009/test D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='xmpp.example.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
05-21 21:27:53.788  25643-26010/test D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='4179863647' from='xmpp.example.com' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'><stream:features><compression xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/compress'><method>zlib</method></compression><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='hX7OB6oTZugjNIFHZvd95k5UYzc='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
05-21 21:27:54.229  25643-26009/test D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>ADEwMDAAMTAwMA==</auth>
05-21 21:27:59.264  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
05-21 21:27:59.454  25643-26010/test W/AbstractXMPPConnection﹕ Connection closed with error
    org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$SecurityRequiredByClientException: SSL/TLS required by client but not supported by server
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.afterFeaturesReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:898)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.parseFeatures(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:1367)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$800(XMPPTCPConnection.java:139)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:998)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
            at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-21 21:27:59.494  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:250)
05-21 21:27:59.494  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginNonAnonymously(XMPPTCPConnection.java:365)
05-21 21:27:59.524  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:452)
05-21 21:27:59.544  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:427)
05-21 21:27:59.574  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at test.Managers.XMPPManager.login(XMPPManager.java:84)
05-21 21:27:59.594  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at test.API.LoginAPI.callAPI(LoginAPI.java:31)
05-21 21:27:59.604  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at test.API.BaseAPI$XMPPTask.doInBackground(BaseAPI.java:70)
05-21 21:27:59.624  25643-25647/test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1558K, 17% free 30564K/36743K, paused 13ms+32ms, total 111ms
05-21 21:27:59.624  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at test.API.BaseAPI$XMPPTask.doInBackground(BaseAPI.java:45)
05-21 21:27:59.624  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-21 21:27:59.624  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-21 21:27:59.664  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-21 21:27:59.664  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-21 21:27:59.664  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-21 21:27:59.664  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-21 21:27:59.664  25643-25970/test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**PS:**
I need the solution in Smack 4.1.1. My code is already working good in aSmack, I need it to upgrade it in Smack. I guess it's clear now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, that was rather a silly mistake. The current code is perfectly fine. I accidentally put username in place of password. I got to know about the error when I tried to go back to aSmack.

Comment: And in my case I was sending the wrong username and password ;-)

Comment: I did the exact same mistake OMG

Answer (score 25):

I was facing the same error.

After connecting to xmpp server I was calling

```
mConnection.login("test@192.168.0.166", "ilink@2012");
```

and it was not working.
To solve the issue I have done the following changes in my code.

```
SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
mConnection.login("test", "ilink@2012");
```

I have added two lines which blacklist DIGEST-MD5 and enable PLAIN SASLMechanism and also removed IP address from username.

For your reference here is my complete working code.

```
package com.ilink.xmpptest;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ConnectionListener {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private AbstractXMPPConnection mConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ConnectToXmppServer().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Authenticated");
    }

    @Override
    public void connected(XMPPConnection arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
        try {
            SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
            SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
            mConnection.login("test", "ilink@2012");
        } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection closed on error");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Reconnecting in");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Reconnection failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Reconnection successful");
    }

    private class ConnectToXmppServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i(TAG, "Connecting to xmpp server started...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
                        .builder()
                        .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                        .setServiceName("192.168.0.166")
                        .setHost("192.168.0.166")
                        .setPort(5222)
                        .setCompressionEnabled(false).build();
                mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
                mConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(1000);
                mConnection.addConnectionListener(MainActivity.this);
                mConnection.connect();
            } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connecting to xmpp server finished...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The lack of documentation about this issue is simply atrocious, I've been searching for pieces of info about this for 2 days without much success... Your post is by far the most helpful I've seen.

Answer (score 5):

For authorization policy,

PLAIN Auth - Unblacklist PLAIN, Blacklist SHA-1 AND MD5

MD5 Auth - Unblacklist MD5, Blacklist SHA-1 AND PLAIN

SCRAM-SHA-1 Auth - Unblacklist SCRAM-SHA-1 & PLAIN, Blacklist MD5

```
SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("AuthName");
SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("AuthName");
```

AuthNames : `PLAIN`, `SCRAM-SHA-1`, `MD5`

** Check at server side that which auth method enabled

Answer (score 4):

```
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("SCRAM-SHA-1");
        SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");
        SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
```

worked for me for non SSL connections. (on connected method)

EDIT:
if the user account has been created on the server you may get this error. check whether it comes from signup (account create) or login.

Answer (score 0):

I think following property will work for you, I am using 3.1

```
config.setVerifyChainEnabled(false);
config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
config.setDebuggerEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This is not really a correct answer. XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration doesn't have all these methods. I guess you are answering on the perspective of aSmack. My question is asking about Smack 4.1.1

Comment: I am using 3.1 , That is why I rote I think